# Using ngx-mask in my Angular project, able to enter all characters, letters and numbers except '@'

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular17

This is my input field.

```
<input id="otp" class="form-control" name="otp" formControlName="otp [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" [patterns]="customPatterns" mask="BBBBBBBBBB" [showMaskTyped]="true">
```

This is the customPatterns to define regular expression:

```
this.customPatterns = { B: { pattern: new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9@$%&#~]') } };
```

Here I am able to enter small alphabets (a-z), capital alphabets (A-Z), numbers (0-9), special characters (~, #, $, %, &) but not able to enter (@).

If I remove 'showMaskTyped' from input field, then I am able to enter '@', but I need mask typed in my input field.

Why 'showMaskTyped' is affecting only '@', anyone knows the issue?

I am working on latest Angular 17.

package.json

```
"ngx-mask":"^17.0.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact issue but when i added property,

```
[specialCharacters]="[]"
```

to my input field it started working as expected. Just in case if anyone facing similar issue, try this once.

So, this will be the final input field:

```
<input id="otp" class="form-control" name="otp" formControlName="otp [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" [specialCharacters]="[]" [patterns]="customPatterns" mask="BBBBBBBBBB" [showMaskTyped]="true">
```